# Google App engine change parent of entity that is not stored

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I know we cant change the parent of an entity that is stored , but can we change the parent of the entity that is not stored? For example i am declaring a model as 
    my_model = MyModel(parent = ParentModel1.key)

but after some checks i may have to change the parent of my_model (i have not run my_model.put() ) to ParentModel2. How can i do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You still can't do it. You should probably delay instantiation of the MyModel object until you know its parent. Perhaps you could collect the attributes in a dictionary, then when it comes to instantiation you can do `my_instance = MyModel(parent=parent_instance, **kwargs)`.

Answer (score 1):

create a new model with the data from the existing one..

or don't create the model until you have all the facts.